# how to work with images and database in android?

Tags: android, database, image, sqlite

I have a quick question regarding to images stored in the drawable(s) folder and a database that has a table with image path. I am using sqlite and my images are png extension. How can I make it work with my database that has an image path and the R.drawable? How can I make a better use of my image path and assing the corresponding image to the corresponding record?

for example:

In my database, I have a table called deck and one of the column stores not a full path of the image but a partial path. Something like this:

```
 Deck
 ---------------
 /Allimages/lod/blueeyes.png
 /Allimages/dk1/darkhole.png
  .
  .
  .
  ( to N record)
```

the Allimages folder is stored within the drawable-ldpi folder. By the way, I have 6000 unique records in the table. What is the best approach for this problem?

Comment: I’m not quite sure I understand you correctly, but assuming you’re trying to reference images from the drawable folders, wouldn’t an id number be a viable solution? E.g.: instead of `/Allimages/lod/blueeyes.png` path, you store the integer `R.drawable.blueeyes` in the database. Also, I would advise against having subfolders in `drawable-*` dirs.

Comment: You can't keep subdirectories inside the drawable folder. If at all you do, the images inside the folder won't be available for use in the app. For android version < 2.2, the app won't even compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`the Allimages folder is stored within the drawable-ldpi folder.`
This is **not possible**. You can't have subfolders in the drawable folders.

Store the images in a drawable folder like:

- lod_blueeyes.png
- dk1_darkhole.png

and so on.

Then, I'd store only the image names (without extension) in my db.
Then, I'd use a function to retrieve the images from the drawable folder:

```
protected final static int getResourceID
(final String resName, final String resType, final Context ctx)
{
    final int ResourceID =
        ctx.getResources().getIdentifier(resName, resType,
            ctx.getApplicationInfo().packageName);
    if (ResourceID == 0)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException
        (
            "No resource string found with name " + resName
        );
    }
    else
    {
        return ResourceID;
    }
}
```

Usage: To retrieve the correct image

```
myImageView.setBackgroundResource
    (
        getResourceID
        (
            "my_image_name", "drawable", getApplicationContext()
        )
    );
```