# How to assing an Image to Imageview based on a query results?

Tags: android, database, image, sqlite, imageview

Good afternoon everyone,

I have a quick question. I have a query result that I store in a list/array and I am trying to display the appropriate image in the imageview. The query provides a name of the image that is stored in the resource folder(res/drawable). I am getting error syntax. I am not sure how to solve this issue. I have a database that stores the name of the image in a field (database) called spic.

I have tried this code:

[how to work with images and database in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755122/how-to-work-with-images-and-database-in-android)

but it doesnt work in this class. I am not sure is it because this class is "extends ArrayAdapter {" instead of "extends Activity {"

here is my code:

zCustomUsersAdapter class:

```
  package com.example.yao;

  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;

  import android.content.Context;
  import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;
  import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
  import android.widget.ImageView;
  import android.widget.TextView;

  public class zCustomUsersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<YAOYVD> {

      public zCustomUsersAdapter(Context context, List<YAOYVD> users) {
          super(context, 0, users);

       }

       @Override
       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
          // Get the data item for this position
         // User user = getItem(position);
           YAOYVD user = getItem(position); 
          // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
          if (convertView == null) {
             convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.zitem_user, parent, false);
          }
          // Lookup view for data population
          TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
          TextView tvHome = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvHometown);

          ImageView tvImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivUserIcon);
          // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
          tvName.setText(String.valueOf(user.getID_YAO()));
                //.name);
          tvHome.setText(String.valueOf(user.getNAME_YAO()));
          //.hometown);

        //  tvImage.setBackgroundResource( getResourceID (String.valueOf(user.getSPIC_YAO()), "drawable",getApplicationContext() ));
          // Return the completed view to render on screen


          tvImage.setBackgroundResource(user.getSPIC_YAO());  //getSpic_YAO this is string in the YAO class. getSpic_YAO retrive the name of the image in the drawable folder.

         return convertView;
     }

 }
```

zCustomListActivity

```
 package com.example.yao;

 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.database.SQLException;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.ImageView;
 import android.widget.ListView;

 public class zCustomListActivity extends Activity {

     private YAOGetDataSource2 datasource;


     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.zactivity_custom_list);

        //calling the method to create the database from asset folder
         copydbfromassest();

        // datasource = new YAODeckListDataSource(this);
        datasource = new YAOGetDataSource2(this);
         datasource.open();


         populateUsersList();

    }



     private void populateUsersList() {
         // Construct the data source
         //List<YAOYVD> values = datasource.SQLYVDTABLESEARCH();  
         List<YAOYVD> arrayOfUsers = datasource.SQLYVDTABLESEARCH(); 
                //.getUsers();
         // Create the adapter to convert the array to views
         zCustomUsersAdapter adapter = new zCustomUsersAdapter(this, arrayOfUsers);
         // Attach the adapter to a ListView
         ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvUsers);
         listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

     //@Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


         //database open and close
         @Override
         protected void onResume() {
         datasource.open();
         super.onResume();
         }

         @Override
         protected void onPause() {
         datasource.close();
         super.onPause();
         }

         @Override
         protected void onDestroy(){
           datasource.close();
           super.onDestroy();

         }


     /****
     * new things to considered
     */
         ///copy the database from assest folder

         private void copydbfromassest() {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             YAOMySQLiteHelper myhelper = new YAOMySQLiteHelper (this);

            try{
                //create datbase
                myhelper.importIfNotExist();
             }catch (IOException e){

                throw new Error("Unable to Create the Database ");

             }

            try{
                myhelper.openDataBase();
            }catch (SQLException sqle){

                throw sqle;
            }
         }

 }
```

Comment: Make sure that what you save in `spic` doesn't contain any path nor extension - only the **file name**.

Comment: spic only contains a word not the extention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to retrieve the resource identifier associated with that image's name. For this, you will need to get your app's Resources, which requires a context.

```
Context ctx = getContext();
int resId = ctx.getResources().getIdentifier(user.getSPIC_YAO(), "drawable", ctx.getPackageName());
if(resId != 0){
    tvImage.setBackgroundResource(resId);
}
```

Comment: hi, I removed this code "tvImage.setBackgroundResource(user.getSPIC_YAO());" and I added your code. Now, I am get an error regarding resource not found. What does this mean? In my database there are 8220 unique records and I only have 4400 images. Could this be the problem? Is there a way where a if condition validates if is not found replace it with a another image?

Comment: Did you include the check for `resId != 0`? It should be 0 if the resource wasn't found, so you shouldn't get an error.

Comment: First of all Thank you and yes I did. I added "log.i("tag", resId);" within the your if condition and then I got a sets of numbers but when I compare them to R.java the numbers doesnt match. For example, the first Image in the cursor is file name is "a7" and in the log its Id is "86988864". Then, I compare it to R.java with the Id and there where no match found but with the name it found it. In the R.java is register as a7=0x7f02004. My question is why is it different?

Comment: I'm not sure why it would be different, something isn't working right. Have you looked for `0x52F5840` in R.java? (Corresponds to the number you got in your logcat).

Comment: yea i get that error "android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x52f5840" I try looking up in the r.java and is not there. Could it be that I use file extension .png instead of .jpg in my res/drawable folder?

Comment: My only other guesses are: clean & rebuild project, or perhaps the package name is not the one you expect? I'm not sure what else to suggest, I've done a local test of getIdentifier() and it's returning the correct ids.

Comment: I would like to thank everyone for helping me out. I found what was the problem. the sql query was passing the wrong column into the cursor. I replaced "user.getSPIC_YAO()" with an image name that I  knew it was there like "a7" and it work. The Image "a7" was showing. Then, I made a  Log.i("Tag:resId ", "cursor:"+ user.getSPIC_YAO()+ " "+ "ResId :" + resId); to see and compare what was it passing into it. Then, I notice that it was not string (name of the images) then, I went back to the my sql syntax and was there... wrong column. Now, it work like a charm. Thank you everyone! I am learning.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! Don't forget to upvote & accept if the answer was helpful. :)